# Copy files from ec2 to s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

How do copy files from given location from Linux ec2 instances to S3 bucket using Java lambda?  Is there any better way to copy the files from ec2 to s3 ?

Regards,

Chamu.

Comment: Generally one copies files from EC2 with a program running on the EC2 instance using the AWS SDK, or simply with the AWS CLI, not using Lambda.

Comment: Why do you wish to use an AWS Lambda function to copy the files? How is the Lambda function being triggered?

Comment: The OP needs to narrow down the question! Check out this link and read through the documentation on what to do technically [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonS3.html)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions do not have access to disks on Amazon EC2 instances.

It is normally easier to send files from the Amazon EC2 instance to Amazon S3. This can be done with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), or via a Java program that uses the AWS SDK for Java.

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to narrow down your question to avoid broad answers.
You can transfer file from ec2 instance to s3 bucket using lambda function.
Follow the below steps:

> ```
> Create an IAM role with s3FullAccess and Ec2FullAccess
>
> Create a s3 bucket
>
> create a lambda function and try to run the below code.
> ```

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    status = client.describe_instance_status(IncludeAllInstances = True)
    s3.upload_file("/home/test/testfile_sample.txt","bucket_name","testfile/testing/")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body' : json.dumps('Hello AWS World')
    }
```

Please go through the following AWS documentation guide lines:

1. [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html)
2. [Use Amazon S3 with Amazon
   EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonS3.html)
3. [AWS
   Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html#when-to-use-cloud-functions)